# Does Cassandra need Autocompaction for completely immutable data?

Tags: optimization, cassandra

I am trying to optimize performance of a Cassandra Table we have in production that is classic event data with timestamps. Going through the different settings, I've been spending some time looking at compaction strategys and wat compaction in cassandra does.

At first, I thought that TimeWindowCompaction was Ideal for our use case, but then I realized that we never delete or update Data.

Is it possible that it is better to disable compaction completely? How are SSTables formed when there is no compaction strategy at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSTables are written to disk when in memory storage (memtables) becomes full or is flushed. If you disable compaction on a table you will end up with a lot of very small SSTables. Regardless of whether you are going to update or delete data you need to compact the data as it is written.

Which compaction strategy you use is going to be depend on your access requirements. [This](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configChooseCompactStrategy.html) is a good basic guide to choosing a compaction strategy and [this](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/compaction.html) is a more detailed guide to compaction in cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling compaction is really not a good option but you can change compaction strategy based on your application behaviour.In your case you can go with Size Tiered Compaction Strategy or Leveled Compaction Strategy.

However,TimeWindowCompactionStrategy is a good option for time series data.
You may refer details as below to understand the use cases.

**TimeWindowCompactionStrategy (TWCS) is designed specifically for workloads where it’s beneficial to have data on disk grouped by the timestamp of the data, a common goal when the workload is time-series in nature or when all data is written with a TTL. In an expiring/TTL workload, the contents of an entire SSTable likely expire at approximately the same time, allowing them to be dropped completely.**

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/compaction.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am however still unsure as to why I need a compaction strategy. Does compaction do something other than removing tombstones and merging updates? Is there some problem with having all data in 1 ssTable?

Comment: If you don't delete or update still compaction has many benefits like system metadata  compaction, merging small sstables etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, as writes occur, memory is flushed to disk under certain conditions. Each time that occurs you get an sstable. Over time, as changes continue, you'll have multiple sstables that make up your table on that node. Assuming you have multiple sstables for a table, you could have a "row" that sits in more than one sstable, and when a read occurs for that row, Cassandra will have to read all sstables for that row, merge the results, and then respond. This slows the reads down. Remember, Cassandra is highly optimized for writes, reads pay the price. Compaction is also used, as you mentioned, for tombstone/delete cleanup.

You get to decide how compaction occurs. The default is size tiered compaction strategy (STCS). The algorithm for this strategy is that when X sstables are of similar size, they get compacted together into a new sstable (and the old sstables discarded). If the result of the new sstable is larger (e.g. 4 sstables compacted into 1, and all rows are unique), it could be a long while before it's eligible to participate in a compaction again (due to needing X of them of the same size to qualify). Does that make sense?

To your point of "why not just have one sstable". For reads, a single sstable that's "packed up" is optimal. However, over time, you'll have new sstables as changes occur (sstables will always be generated for new changes - you can't stop that), and your one large sstable, as mentioned before may not be eligible to get cleaned up, causing performance to degrade again. That's STCS.

There are other strategies - each optimized for certain conditions. The idea is to keep things as clean as possible without overwhelming the system with continuously compacting data - thus the different approaches/strategies to choose from. Each with benefits and deficits to others.

The other thing to remember is that reads occur at the partition level. If you had a table where the partition key was the primary key and every row was inserted without deletes, ttls or anything else in that nature, then you're correct, compaction would not be needed at all for that type of table. You could have 1 million sstables and it wouldn't matter. However, if you have a primary key where partition key is part, but not all of it, read performance could be affected (Reads occur at the partition level, and you'll have multiple rows and sstables for every partition). In that scenario, you may not need compaction for cleanup (again assuming only inserts, no ttls/deletes, etc), but the more sstables for a single partition, the slower your reads may be (Depending on how many sstables each partition resides, and the use of some built-in optimizations that filter out sstables for partitions ).

Hopefully that helps.